# Dynamic class loading: Why Null pointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classloader, executable-jar

I have a java application that contains a folder named "Loadedstrategies" in bin directory. This folder contains some jar files that I load dynamically. Application works fine when running from eclipse but when I convert my application into a jar file and run the jar file then a null pointer exception is thrown.
The  null pointer exception is thrown at following statement

```
URL url=(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Loadedstrategies"));
```

I printed the value of url which is null ie above statement is not taking url.

i am saving my jar file at path bin/Loadedstrategies. My application is loading jar files from bin/Loadedstrategies correctly from eclipse by above statement but not when I convert application into jar. Kindly help me

Comment: please try with fully qualified name, instead of just class name.

Comment: When exporting in Eclipse, you can change `Library handling`. There you can select if the Libraries are imported in the .jar file, or if the Libraries will be included externally. Maybe you need to play around with this, to get the .jar to work

Comment: Are you trying to load jars from inside another jar? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed something like this and did the following:

```
URL myurl = new URL("file://" + PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR);  
URLClassLoader classloader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{myurl});  
Class<MY_INTERFACE> myclass = = (Class<MY_INTERFACE>) classloader.loadClass(NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS);
MY_INTERFACE myinst = myclass.newInstance();
```

p.s. "file://" is for linux, for windows try using "file:///" you can check the os with System.getProperty("os.name")

Comment: As I have mentioned I provide my application as a runnable jar file and my client can store that jar file at any path which is unknown to me so the complete path to my dynamically loadable jar is not known . The only thing which is known is that the runnable jar file of my application contains a folder named Loadedstrategies that contains jar files that I need to load dynamically. Kindly tell me how to specify the path to Loadedstrategies folder.

Comment: this is exactly my situation as well... the path to the jar can be given as an argument to your app or method of your app... try it... it works!

Comment: I don't want user to indulge into difficulties of giving complex paths after running my application. Just tell me that do you know how to specify the path of Loadedstrategies folder which is stored in My application runnable jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have the following organization:

```
application jar
 |_ bin
 |   |_ Loadedstrategies
 |_ src
 ...
```

If so use:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("bin/Loadedstrategies");
```

Comment: Loadedstrategies is a folder that contains jar files that I need to load and run dynamically loadedstrategies is not a jar file. kindly understand my real problem. My problem is " how to specify the path of folder called loadedstrategies that contain my dynamic jar files. loadedstrategies is a folder in my applications jar file. I want to dynamically read the path of loadedstrategies folder.

Comment: In my answer I didn't say that Loadedstrategies is a jar file. I just described 2 ways to retrieve the path of Loadedstrategies folder.

Comment: Sorry I missed that Loadedstrategies is inside your application jar. I update my answer.